# how to get <bean:write> value to be used in <html:text size="?">

Tags: java, list, jsp, javabeans, struts-1

Does anyone know how to set the size at my input box?

My code:

```xhtml
<logic:iterate id="aList" name="SomeForm" property="MyList">
<html:text styleClass="input-text" name="SomeForm" property="lalalala"
size="<bean:write name="aList" property="SomeLength">">
</logic:iterate>
```

In this code the value inside the bean cannot be read in the size property but if I put the bean outside,the value can be seen.
Can anybody help? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSP EL like this:

```
<logic:iterate id="aList" name="SomeForm" property="MyList">
    <html:text styleClass="input-text" name="SomeForm" property="lalalala"
    size="${aList.SomeLength}">
</logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the length from `aList` like this first :

```
<bean:define id="leng" name="aList" property="SomeLength"/>
```

then use it :

```
<html:text styleClass="input-text" name="SomeForm" property="lalalala" size="<%=leng%>">
```

Comment: THANKS BRO! YOU GIVE ME THE SOLUTION!